# How to Access the Return Value of One Function In Another Function?

Tags: php

I have one function that ends with:

```
return $authors;
```

How can I access this value in another function within the same class?

I've tried (in the second function)

```
$this->authors;
```

But it doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Either you pass it to the next method as parameter or you first assign `$autor` to a class property, e.g. `$this->author = $author;`

Comment: You.... call the function? Suppose your function's named `getAuthor`.. you'd then call `$this->getAuthor()`

Comment: @ccKep, right, but if our hypothetical getAuthor() needs parameters to run, how do we get the existing parameters that are set in getAuthor() over to the second function in order to run getAuthor() again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function returnAuthor()
{
   return $author;
}

public function anotherMethod()
{
   return $this->returnAuthor();
}
```

You could follow a similar method as stated in the above example.
or you could define a property for your class, have one function assign a value to it and have another function return the value

Like so

```
class Book
{
   public $author;

   function __construct()
   {
      $this->author = 'Sir Conan Doyle';
   }

   function anotherMethod()
   {
      return $this->author;
   }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: What if I want to return it as a variable that I can use. I've trying this in the second function and not getting anything back: `$authorList = $this->authors;
  var_dump($authorList);`

Comment: $authors is an array, if that matters.

Comment: That's about it to be honest, if you get null it must be something else. Doesn't look like you're doing anything wrong. Hard to tell without your code.

Take a look -> http://notey.it/n/dDFw